# Did tobacco smoke confound the results of an experiment by entering a reaction with the subject of study?

Tags: experimental-physics, chemistry

I dimly remember watching a popular sciencie movie that mentioned an experiment conducted by a pair of great physisicists (Einstein was one of them, unless my memory is playing tricks on me) that had surprising results, because they were both heavy smokers and their tobacco smoke entered an unforseen reaction with the subject of study.

Very sadly, I forgot all other details.

Was there such a situation? What were they experimenting on? What was this reaction that gave misleading results?

Comment: Do you mean de Haas and Einstein? Einstein's pipe was heavily fuming but Im not sure it was when experimenting. I cant imagine Einstein doing experiments though. I tend to think of him as a theoretical guy. What did you get when Goggling him and experiment?

Comment: The only experiment E did was with his little machine.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder I may have been wrong, it may have been another psysicist, not Einstein.

Comment: Can you remember the experiment?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder I know this would be very helpful, but sadly, I don't. To be honest this is the main purpose of my question: I'd like to know what things (other than the human body) can tobacco smoke enter a reaction with.

Comment: I tried goggling (googling) but only experiments about smoking and cancer turned up. Where to look? I dunno..

Comment: "*only experiments about smoking and cancer turned up*" - that's the problem sadly :( I also tried googling and I also was only getting results about health hazards.

Comment: Yes. Thats indeed the reason you asked your question...If you're lucky somebody here knows!

Comment: Too little information to be a useful question.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Unless somebody knows about a smokey coincidence leading to a new chemical reaction... But I agree, it is very summise

Comment: Found a scientific reference :-)   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6Je0rHIal4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short Answer

I believe you are thinking of the [Stern–Gerlach experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment#History). Which was instrumental in the discovery of quantized angular momentum at the time it was thought to prove the Bohr model, but later was experimental proof that subatomic particles have quantized spin. I think you might have been confused, because the cigar smoke actually helped them view an experiment by converting trace amounts  of silver metal to silver sulfate.

### Background

**Otto Stern** graduated with a PhD in Physics in 1912. He became Albert Einstein's first pupal at the Charles University in Prague. They would investigate the quantization of light, magnetism, and statistical physics. All of which would be the back bone of his Nobel prize winning experiment. After World War 1 Stern would become Max Born assistant at the Institute for Theoretical Physics where he started his work with molecular beams. He would improve on [Louis Dunoyer's early molecular beam](https://www.encyclopedia.com/science/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/dunoyer-de-segonzac-louis-dominique-joseph-armand) experiment that would later become the Stern–Gerlach experiment.

**Walther Gerlach** received his PhD in physics at the University of Tübingen where he researched black body radiation, and the photoelectric effect. Gerlach also became an assistant at the  Institute for Theoretical Physics. He to had been interested in the molecular beam experiments carried out by Dunoyer. Using them to observer the emission spectra of beams from different metals without any success.

**The physical landscape** at the time was dominated by the Bohr model. There were some issues that the model couldn't explained.

At the time spatial quantization wasn't thought of as a "real" thing. It was thought of as an abstraction of some yet to be understood phenomena. The experiment would receive backlash from Born, and other physicist at the institute before it even took place. Born would write,

> It took me quite a long time before I took this idea seriously. I thought always that [space] quantization was a kind of symbolic expression for something which you don't understand.

### Experiment

The apparatus was composed of a beam of silver atoms collimated between two slits. These beams were directed over a 0.1tesla, 3.5cm magnet. The beam would cause a build up of silver metal on the glass. The classical thought was that a atomic magnet entering a field would oriented randomly, and the deflected atoms would only widen the beam. Where as quantum theory predicted the beam would split. At the time misalignments, and repeated failures of the apparatus led to a relatively short runs, and not much build up of silver.

When they vented the vacuum in the apparatus to measure the result they initially saw no sign of silver build up, but as the silver metal was exposed to the atmosphere they began to see a build  up of black material.

As is still the case postdocs didn't make a lot of money, so Stern would smoke really cheap cigars. When they vented the vacuum in the experiment the silver was reacting with sulfur from the cheap cigar smoke forming silver sulfide. The now tarnished silver which is black was much easier to see.

[2Ag (s) + H2S (g) → Ag2 S (s) + H2 (g)](https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-silver-sulfide-chemical-formula-uses.html#:%7E:text=Silver%20sulfide%20is%20generated%20when,t%20have%20many%20beneficial%20uses.)

Even still they ran into experimental issues, and colleges reluctant to take their results seriously. Even worse the country was in the midst of a financial crisis, and the pair had to scrape money together to fund the experiment. Stern had moved to Rostock to teach physics. In 1922 they met in Göttingen to discuss and work on the project. Due to a train workers strike keeping Gerlach in Göttingen longer then expected they were able to get a well aligned beam that finally gave them good data.

### Results!

At the time the results matched with the Bohr model, and came within 10% of his predicted magnetic moment of [one Bohr Magneton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_magneton). Spatial quantization was some of the best evidence of quantum theory at the time. The Bohr model would soon be obsolete, and would lead to a new understanding of the Stern–Gerlach experiment. The splitting was not a result of the angular momentum of the silver atom, but actually due to the half [spin angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#History). Pauli wouldn't publish about spin until 1924 two years after the experiment was preformed.

Gerlach would remain in Germany. He never joined the Nazi party, but he would lead the German effort to develop an atomic bomb. After hearing of the bomb being dropped on Hiroshima he suffered a nervous break down. He would be a stanch advocate for banning nuclear weapons, and work on repairing German science.

Stern immigrated to the united states in 1939, and worked for the War department in World War 2. He would never return to Germany. Stern would receive the Nobel price in 1943, not for the Stern–Gerlach experiment, but "[for his contribution to the development of the molecular ray method and his discovery of the magnetic moment of the proton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nobel_laureates_in_Physics)".

---

This was a summery of the article "[Stern and Gerlach: How a Bad Cigar Helped Reorient Atomic Physics](https://faculty.chemistry.harvard.edu/files/dudley-herschbach/files/how_a_bad_cigar_0.pdf?m=1363959307)". I had never heard of this experiment, and found it very interesting.

Comment: I can make this more condensed, but I thought the background might be interesting.

Comment: "well aliened" -> "well aligned"?